# To Automate a dropdown box without Select tag using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu, webdriver

I'm trying to automate a drop down box in home page of [HDFC bank](http://www.hdfcbank.com/) in which by default 'Net banking' is selected. It does not have a `Select` tag and it has `div` tag. Also I tried to click on the drop down first and select the values one by one, but I'm getting error like

> Element can't be clicked

Please help me with this.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("selectedvalue")).click(); //Error for this statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.loginwrap > div.selectWrapper > div.selectedvalue")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("prepaidcard")).click();
```

I generated this from Selenium IDE for firefox. It is a plugin for Firefox which you can record user actions and export the test case to Java ( among many other languages).
This is the link [Selenium IDE](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/)

Comment: Chetan_K, glad to help you. I strongly recommend you to try Selenium IDE as it is very useful in creating a selenium test case quickly.

Comment: Cool, Definitely i'll use going forward :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try for :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'NetBanking')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='prepaidcard']")).click();
```